How can I fix an AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient?
I've tried everything and done a lot of research to fix this problem, but nothing works. My goal was to convert my HTML file to PDF with Chromium Headless, but I got this error:
johndoe@domain:/var/www$ chromium --headless --disable-gpu --no-sandbox --no-pdf-header-footer --print-to-pdf='/home/johndoe/407163caf78c6deedcb8bf732e7e1326-fr.pdf' 'https://files.domain.com/docs/407163caf78c6deedcb8bf732e7e1326.html' && mv '/home/johndoe/407163caf78c6deedcb8bf732e7e1326-fr.pdf' '/var/www/files.domain.com/docs/' && echo 'files.transladocs.com/docs/407163caf78c6deedcb8bf732e7e1326-fr.pdf'
[17035:17192:1111/053835.545588:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.ListActivatableNames: object_path= /org/freedesktop/DBus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.71" (uid=1000 pid=17035 comm="/snap/chromium/2992/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrom" label="snap.chromium.chromium (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="ListActivatableNames" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)                                      
[17035:17192:1111/053835.604277:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.ListActivatableNames: object_path= /org/freedesktop/DBus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.73" (uid=1000 pid=17035 comm="/snap/chromium/2992/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrom" label="snap.chromium.chromium (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="ListActivatableNames" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)                                      
754773 bytes written to file /home/john/407163caf78c6deedcb8bf732e7e1326-fr.pdf                                        
files.domain.com/docs/407163caf78c6deedcb8bf732e7e1326-fr.pdf                     
johndoe@domain:/var/www$ 

I couldn't use Google Chrome Headless, because my server is an ARM64 server and Google Chrome Headless doesn't support ARM64 but rather AMD64.
and after these errors that it has been converted. I could try to leave it like that but when I try to use it directly in my site nothing with PHP code works.
Here's my PHP code:
<?php
$command = "chromium --headless --disable-gpu --no-sandbox --no-pdf-header-footer --print-to-pdf='/home/joedoe/407163caf78c6deedcb8bf732e7e1326-fr.pdf' 'https://files.domain.com/docs/407163caf78c6deedcb8bf732e7e1326.html' && mv '/home/joendoe/407163caf78c6deedcb8bf732e7e1326-fr.pdf' '/var/www/files.domain.com/docs/' && echo 'files.domain.com/docs/407163caf78c6deedcb8bf732e7e1326-fr.pdf'";

$output = [];
$returnStatus = 0;

// Execute the command and capture the output and status
exec($command . ' 2>&1', $output, $returnStatus);

// Display output and status for debugging
echo "Return Status: $returnStatus\n";
echo "Output:\n" . implode("\n", $output);

if ($returnStatus !== 0) {
    echo "Command failed.\n";
} else {
    echo "Command succeeded.\n";
}

What do you think is going on and what should I do to fix it? Any help or ideas will help me a lot.

It's not working too well. Just look at:
chromium --headless=old --disable-gpu --no-sandbox --no-pdf-header-footer --print-to-pdf='/home/richardson/aacaafa8a54b31d8e67b922ab90cacd1-fr.pdf' 'https://files.domain.co/docs/aacaafa8a54b31d8e67b922ab90cacd1.html' [1115/040745.602327:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(430)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process. [1115/040745.607274:WARNING:viz_main_impl.cc(85)] VizNullHypothesis is disabled (not a warning)  779921 bytes written to file /home/joedoe/aacaafa8a54b31d8e67b922ab90cacd1-fr.pdf

And in my browser, it displays this:
Return Status: 1 Output: cmd_run.go:1276: WARNING: cannot create user data directory: cannot create snap home dir: mkdir /var/www/snap: permission denied /system.slice/php8.3-fpm.service is not a snap cgroupCommand failed.
So, what should I do in this case?

No. It's no better because it works differently in my browser. This result 779921 bytes written to file is the one when the command is run in the shell of my ARM64 VPS Ubuntu server. But when I'm in development mode in my site browser. It gives me this result Return Status: 1 Output: cmd_run.go:1276: WARNING: cannot create user data directory: cannot create snap home dir: mkdir /var/www/snap: permission denied /system.slice/php8.3-fpm.service is not a snap cgroupCommand failed.. So, what should I do in this case please?

So, what do you suggest me to do in this case?
